# npm install does not care package-lock.json

Tags: linux, jenkins, npm, package-lock.json

My npm install on jenkins installs a version of a package other than defined in the package-lock.json.

When I run it locally (on a windows), it works as expected, 1.4.10 of cleave.js package is installed. Though, when I run it through jenkins, it installs a different version, 1.5.3.

When I checked the jenkins build logs, it looks like it installs the package from a  cached binary.

```
Cached binary found at /var/lib/jenkins/.npm/node-sass/4.12.0/linux-x64-57_binding.node
> core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CI-MyProject-Demo/build/exports/MyProject/MyProject-web/node_modules/core-js
> node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"

> sauce-connect-launcher@1.2.7 postinstall /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CI-MyProject-Demo/build/exports/MyProject/MyProject-web/node_modules/sauce-connect-launcher
> node scripts/install.js || nodejs scripts/install.js

> node-sass@4.12.0 postinstall /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CI-MyProject-Demo/build/exports/MyProject/MyProject-web/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Binary found at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CI-MyProject-Demo/build/exports/MyProject/MyProject-web/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57/binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine
sfra@4.0.0 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CI-MyProject-Demo/build/exports/MyProject/MyProject-web

...
│   └── rimraf@2.7.1 
├── cleave.js@1.5.3 
├─┬ cross-env@5.2.1 
...
```

Now, the possible solution I can think of is that I can delete `/var/lib/jenkins/.npm/node-sass/4.12.0/linux-x64-57_binding.node` this file, and it should probably work. But I'm not sure if that would break anything else, or if that's the way to go.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead deleting the module, you could use

```
npm cache clean
```

prior running the install